# Android app throws "Illegal Start of Type"

Tags: android, android-studio

So it's my first time for me to build app with Android Studio and I came up with this error while building my APK file.

```
error: illegal start of type import android.graphics.Bitmap;
```

And this is my code.

```
    package rf.gd.davincana.davincana_aplikasibelajar;

        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

        import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// please help me

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private WebView webView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.davincana.rf.gd/");

        }

        public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;

            }
        }

        @Override
        // This method is used to detect back button
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if(webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
            } else {
                // Let the system handle the back button
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I have no idea, I also search on YouTube and Google, but I came up still without knowing what's going on.

Comment: You should familiarise yourself with basic Java before attempting to write an Android app, otherwise you'll quickly become frustrated. If you aren't comfortable with import statements then I doubt you understand any of this code you've (clearly) pasted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `import` libs inside of a class.

Answer (score 0):

I examined your code. It seems like you tried to copy paste some code from the internet, right? You have **`MainActivity`** class inside of another `MainActivity` class with imports.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// please help me

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

This is not allowed by Java compiler and Java programming language. You have to declare all the import statements before declaring class, enum or interface.

The fixed version of the class would be looking like that. But it only fixed from the perspective of imports and class redundant nesting:

```
package rf.gd.davincana.davincana_aplikasibelajar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private WebView webView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.davincana.rf.gd/");
  }

  public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
      super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

      view.loadUrl(url);
      return true;

    }
  }

  @Override
  // This method is used to detect back button
  public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
      webView.goBack();
    } else {
      // Let the system handle the back button
      super.onBackPressed();
    }
  }
}
```

Also, make a note: **don't use** `android.support.v7` dependenices, use `androidx.appcompat` instead. This is unmaintained version of support library for now. All the bugfixes and improvements are done **for AndroidX artifacts only**.